# duplicate sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have a problem with a sidebar. I have 4 sidebars: "Essential", "Essential+", "Premier" and "Premier+".

```
register_sidebar(
     array(
         'name'          => __('Essential Plan'),
         'before_widget' => '<ul>',
         'after_widget'  => '</ul>',
         'before_title'  => '',
         'after_title'   => ''
    )
);
register_sidebar(
    array(
         'name'          => __('Premier Plan'),
         'before_widget' => '<ul>',
         'after_widget'  => '</ul>',
         'before_title'  => '',
         'after_title'   => ''
    )
);
register_sidebar(
    array(
         'name'          => __('Essential+ Plan'),
         'before_widget' => '<ul>',
         'after_widget'  => '</ul>',
         'before_title'  => '',
         'after_title'   => ''
    )
);
register_sidebar(
    array(
         'name'          => __('Premier+ Plan'),
         'before_widget' => '<ul>',
         'after_widget'  => '</ul>',
         'before_title'  => '',
         'after_title'   => ''
    )
);
```

I have to render "Premier" and "Premier+" in the same page. When I do this WordPress renders the same content for both pages, how can i fix this?
why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a **unique ID** to each dynamic sidebar, via the `id` parameter passed to [**`register_sidebar()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar):

```
register_sidebar(
        array(
             'id'            => 'essential',
             'name'          => __('Essential Plan'),
             'before_widget' => '',
             'after_widget'  => '',
             'before_title'  => '',
             'after_title'   => ''
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
             'id'            => 'premier',
             'name'          => __('Premier Plan'),
             'before_widget' => '',
             'after_widget'  => '',
             'before_title'  => '',
             'after_title'   => ''
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
             'id'            => 'essential-plus',
             'name'          => __('Essential+ Plan'),
             'before_widget' => '',
             'after_widget'  => '',
             'before_title'  => '',
             'after_title'   => ''
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
             'id'            => 'premier-plus',
             'name'          => __('Premier+ Plan'),
             'before_widget' => '',
             'after_widget'  => '',
             'before_title'  => '',
             'after_title'   => ''
        )
    );
```

And then call each one by ID:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'essential' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'premier' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'essential-plus' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'premier-plus' );
```

Though, you *should* be able to call them via `name` *or* `ID`:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'Essential Plan' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'Premier Plan' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'Essential+ Plan' );
dynamic_sidebar( 'Premier+ Plan' );
```

...unless the "+" gets sanitized from the parameter?

Comment: i call them with the name! i guess is a problem with the + symbol, thanks for the ID advice, ill try it

Comment: If the `$index` argument of `dynamic_sidebar($index)` is not an integer, the function calls [`sanitize_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title), which will turn `Premier+ Plan` into `premier-plan`.

Comment: oh thanks, i didn't know that, so i guess my best option is use id

Comment: The thanks ought to address Chip, but other than that, yes, go with id.